# Which prefixing language has the most speakers?

Tags: linguistic-typology, inflection, agglutination, morphological-typology, affixes

Most if not all national or widely spoken languages with an inflecting or agglutinating typology do all of their inflecting at the end of the word. These are called "suffixing languages".

This is true for nouns and verbs in all the European and East Asian languages I know much about.

But there is another possibility where inflectional information is in the form of prefixes attached to the beginning of the word. These are known as "prefixing languages".

Since I can't name any such languages off the top of my head, I'm wondering which language that has this property is the most widely spoken or has the most speakers. Is any a national language, co-official language, or local lingua franca?

(Yes, combinations of both suffixing and prefixing are also possible, as is internal changes like in Semitic languages. Also I'm only asking about inflecting morphology, not derivational morphology, we know European languages use lots of derivation prefixes.)

Comment: Not quite *all* their inflecting - many West Germanic languages (including at one time English) have the *ge-* prefix on the past participle.

Comment: @StoneyB: Ah yes I forgot about that. It's the exception that proves the rule (-;

Comment: Virtually all Bantu languages are prefixing. Swahili is the most widely spoken; it's a trade and contact language.

Comment: @hippietrail And are prepositions *really* words?

Comment: @jlawler: I spotted Xhosa and Zulu in WALS and wondered about Swahili but didn't see it. That would make it clearly the best answer I think. Why not submit an answer?

Comment: @StoneyB: I didn't want to get too philosophical on this question, I just hoped to find a thriving language usually understood to be of prefixing typology. But when considering a philosophical question about which conceptual word classes are "real" you must consider whether words are "real" at all, a famously difficult to pin down concept. But maybe you might ask it as a new question on the site (-:

Comment: Here's a couple [morphosyntax problems on Swahili](http://www.umich.edu/~jawler/SwahiliPuzzles.pdf). Bantu languages are also known for thoroughgoing "gender" agreement systems, with up to twenty "genders", i.e, noun classes.

Comment: `You have requested a resource that is not available on this web server.`

Comment: Ah, I misspelled my URL, and now it's too late to edit it. Sorry. [Here it is again](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/SwahiliPuzzles.pdf), correctly spelled this time.